# When the program can obtain the complete HTML code of a webpage, can XPath be used to locate and retrieve any web page data you want?

Tags: web-scraping

When the program can obtain the complete HTML code of a webpage, can XPath be used to locate and retrieve any web page data you want?So, XPath is more efficient than Beautiful Soup?